# How to save each column of CSV file to separate .TXT files?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, text

As in title, i.e. I have spreadsheet with 4 columns, and I want to save each of them in separate .txt files. Spreadsheet won't have same amount of columns everytime.

Is that possible? Tried to do this with CSVhelper but I don't know how :c

Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi, what have you actually tried? In simplest form you could just read a line, use Split to separate the string using the comma that separates each column and place each into a text file. Hopefully the first line of your csv file will give you the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like the following after installing NPOI to your project:

```
        public static void WriteColumnsToTextFile()
    {
        var readPath = @"C:\readLocation\testing.xlsx";

        using var stream = new FileStream(readPath, FileMode.Open); 
        stream.Position = 0;

        XSSFWorkbook xssWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        //For encrypted spreadsheets use the above else use the below instead
        //HSSFWorkbook xssWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);

        ISheet sheet = xssWorkbook.GetSheet("sheet1"); 
        var columnCount = sheet.GetRow(0).LastCellNum;
        var rowCount = sheet.LastRowNum;

        for (var colNum = 0; colNum < columnCount; colNum++)
        {
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            for (var rowNum = 0; rowNum < sheet.LastRowNum; rowNum++)
            {
                text.Append(sheet.GetRow(rowNum).GetCell(colNum).ToString() + "\n");
            }
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\yourlocationhere\\testing_"+colNum+".txt", text.ToString());
        }

    }
```